# How to use variable in job conditional rule

Tags: github-actions

I want to run a job on condition:
(previous job output returns a string, for example "this is sometext")

```
- name: some job
  if: contains(${{steps.previous-step.outputs.someoutput}}, 'sometext')
  run: echo 'is executed'
```

The problem is that this job is always executed so condition is always true even if `steps.previous-step.outputs.someoutput` does not contain expected text.

But it always works if I use contains function without variable inside, e.g. just
`contains('some other text', 'sometext')`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `${{ }}` when using the `contains` function on a `if` expression.

The correct syntax is:

```yaml
  job1:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
          - id: step1
            run: echo "::set-output name=test::hello"
          - name: step2
            if: contains(steps.step1.outputs.test, 'hello')
            run: echo 'is executed'
          - name: step3
            if: contains(steps.step1.outputs.test, 'not_hello')
            run: echo 'not executed'
```

Here, `step2` will be executed, but not `step3`.

I made an example in [this workflow run (job7)](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/runs/5216353239?check_suite_focus=true) if you want to check.

Comment: you are a genius. thank you!